# Date parsing error while formating a custom Date

Tags: java, datetime-format

I want  to convert this date `"Sat, 16 Nov 2013 20:09:07"` to unixtime

my code

```
SimpleDateFormat pattern = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = pattern.parse("Sat, 16 Nov 2013 20:09:07")
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
```

i got this exception

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat, 16 Nov 2013 20:09:07"
 (at offset 8)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
```

is there a problem with the pattern ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - you're using `MM` which is a *numeric* month pattern. You want `MMM` instead, as that's "abbreviated month name". I'd also suggest explicitly specifying `Locale.US` in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor if you know that the month and day names will be in English (otherwise it'll use the system default locale).

Comment: You are one of the greatest resources in this world . thanks thanks thanks thanks . will check the question after 10 minute.